# What's the meaning of hit play?

Tags: phrases

From NPR: [Wheels On The Bike Go Round And Round (To Make Music)](http://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=269457757)

The story tells that Baber--a music writer, create music out of bikes.

> BABER: When you first tell people you made a piece of music from bikes, they're not exactly eager to hit play.

What's the meaning of "hit play"?

Comment: Hit the 'play' button on a video/dvd player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We "play" a piece of music, eg, on a stereo or mp3 player or similar. "hit play" refers to pushing the "play" button on the device in order to listen to a piece of music. So it means that people don't want to play the music/listen to it.

We also say "hit it!" when we mean to begin something, particularly for a band or performer to begin to perform a song, and we have "hits" meaning popular songs, so this may be why we say "hit play" instead of just "push/press play".